# Asynchronous evaluation on EventHandler

Tags: dynamic

How can I make this progress bar appears when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>? The `Button` Evaluate works just fine, but when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed it jumps the progress bar.

It would be easy if EventHandler could have `Method-> "Queued"`, but is't not the case.

Here is my code:

```
DynamicModule[{output="",slowReport,progress,str,btnEval,enterAction,number,enterEval},

    progress=ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[Clock[Infinity]],Indeterminate,ImageSize->280];

    enterEval=EventHandler[#,{"ReturnKeyDown":>(output=progress;output=slowReport[])}]&;    
    btnEval=Button["Evaluate",(output=progress;output=slowReport[]),Method->"Queued"];

    Dynamic@Panel@Column[{Row[{InputField[Dynamic[number], String]//enterEval,btnEval}]," ",output," "},Alignment->Center]

    ,Initialization:>
   (
       SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,DynamicEvaluationTimeout->10];
       slowReport[]:=(Pause[1];ToExpression@number^2)
    )
]
```

Here is what happens when Evaluate is pressed:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can play with `CellEventActions`.

Comment: There are some ideas here you might be able to use: [Asynchronous evaluation: Is it possible?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238/asynchronous-evaluation-is-it-possible)

Comment: As an FYI `SetDelayed` doesn't work within the body of a `DynamicModule`. You need to use `Initialization`.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, changed into `Initialization`. Tks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 10.1 now supports the `Method->"Queued"` option for `EventHandler`.  Unfortunately, I forgot to document that fact (sorry!).  Documentation updated now for future releases.

Also, your code could be improved by making a progress indicator that doesn't do kernel evaluations.  This progress indicator just runs in the FE and won't get any hiccups from trying to interrupt the kernel to get processing time:

```
ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Indeterminate", ImageSize -> 280]
```

Comment: tks for sharing this John.

Comment: Should I do just this: `EventHandler[#,{"ReturnKeyDown":>(output=progress;output=slowReport[])},Method->"Queued"]`, it's not working for me. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another funny way to do things.  What is needed is a queued submit function like `ParallelSubmit`. One key below is using `DynamicWrapper` to hide an asynchronous updating of `output`.  Another key is "touching" `number` (à la Unix) when the button or enter/return is pressed.  These don't change the value of `number`, so to trigger an update, `touch` changes the value and immediately changes it back.  I moved `Dynamic` from wrapping `Panel` to `output`.  This eliminated each update leading to two calculations of `slowReport`.

```
DynamicModule[{output = "", slowReport, progress, str, btnEval, 
  enterAction, number, enterEval, touch},

 progress =  ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[Clock[Infinity]], Indeterminate, ImageSize -> 280];

 slowReport[n_] /; NumericQ[ToExpression[n]] := (Pause[1]; ToExpression@n^2);
 slowReport[_] := (Pause[1]; "");
 touch = Function[n, (n = ""; n = #) &@n, HoldAll];

 enterEval = EventHandler[#, {"ReturnKeyDown" :> (output = progress; touch[number])}] &;
 btnEval = Button["Evaluate", (output = progress; touch[number]),
    Method -> "Queued"];

 output = progress;

 (*Dynamic@*)
 Panel@Column[
   {Row[{InputField[Dynamic[number, (output = progress; number = #) &], String] //enterEval,
         btnEval}],
    DynamicWrapper[" ", output = slowReport[number], 
      TrackedSymbols :> {number}, SynchronousUpdating -> False],
    Dynamic @ output, " "},
   Alignment -> Center], 
 Initialization :> (SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 10])]
```

By the way, perhaps one might to be able to use `ParallelSubmit` to achieve the goal.

Comment: The second time you press return (without changing input) the progress indicator stays on forever.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks.  Fixed, I think, although in yet another roundabout way.

Comment: Oh my God, why life has always to be so complicated inside `DynamicModule`! @MikeHoneychurch, It's this kind of thing that I complain [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37908/2266) in #1.

Comment: @Murta I know, I know. I keep hoping someone will show the "easy" way that eludes me.  Sometimes they're like objects that find out things by rumor instead of direct object-oriented messaging.

Comment: @Murta while life can sometimes be complicated in `DynamicModule` I don't think that is where the "blame" lies. You are hoping to be able to witness the result of multiple actions from one single `EventHandler` event. My reading of the docs is that this is not possible. I think it is ok to be frustrated with a perceived lack of functionality that may or may not be available within `DynamicModules` but if you try to do something outside what is documented then I don't think there is cause to complain.

Comment: @Murta  Feel free to change the accept, if the new functionality works better for you.  It's good for other if the accepted answers points to the best solution.

Comment: @MichaelE2 tks! Will do that. I too believe it's helpful for new readers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send queued sequence of procedures to the kernel with controller which has not got this `Method` you can mimic this with `ScheduledTasks`.

Notice that this way is useful only for non continuous events like clicks, etc. Because separate scheduled tasks are independent and there is no guarantee of queue.

But for your example it fits quite well:

```
DynamicModule[{
  output = "",
  slowReport,
  progress, 
  number,
  enterEval},
 progress = ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Necklace"];


 enterEval = 
  EventHandler[#, {"ReturnKeyDown" :> 
      RunScheduledTask[output = progress; FinishDynamic[]; 
       output = slowReport[], {.01}]}] &;


 Column[{
   InputField[Dynamic[number], String] // enterEval,
   Dynamic[output, TrackedSymbols :> {output}]
 }],

 Initialization :> (
   slowReport[] := (   Pause[3]; ToExpression@number^2);


   )]
```

> [image]

p.s. do not ask me why there is `TrackedSymbols`... It just won't work without it.